# How to create two subdirectories within a gradle zip task?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to create a zip with some files in a 'bin' directory within the zip and some other files within a 'lib' folder. I tried the following task

```
task makeZip(type: Zip, dependsOn:'assemble') {
    platformGeneratedFilesDirectory
    into('libs')

    from apkDirectory
    into('bin')
```

But it just creates the bin directory and not the libs directory.

I've consulted the documentation http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec%3aarchives

however I find it poorly explained, what for example is

```
from configurations.runtime
```

used for in the example in the documentation, is it relevant to creating subdirectories? If not then how can I place files into different directories within the zip?

Comment: May be 'from' should be in scope of 'into' as in Example 18.18?

`task makeZip(type: Zip, dependsOn:'assemble') {

    into('libs') { platformGeneratedFilesDirectory }

    into('bin') { from apkDirectory }
}`

Comment: Thanks. That worked.